# Disable S/PDIF in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, audio, hdmi, spdif

I'm currently using Ubuntu 21.04 with audio coming from my DisplayPort connected Display. Everytime my PC boots, it defaults to Digital Output (S/PDIF). This is getting me crazy, because I need to change it all the time. When I disconnect my Bluetooth Headphone, it defaults to S/PDIF itself. How can i completely disable S/PDIF, making my HDMI connected audio the default one?

Comment: I found this question while searching for KDE. This is not an answer, but may nudge a future searcher in the right direction. It looks like KDE's `System Settings` -> `Hardware` -> `Audio` section has an "Off" profile.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
Type `sudo apt install pavucontrol` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This command will install the PulseAudio Volume Control application.
Open the PulseAudio Volume Control application.
Click on the Configuration tab.
Find your digital output device and set its profile to Off.